# Не удается запустить проект в Visual Studio,но в диспетчере задач он отображен

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день!
У меня перестал запускаться проект в Visual Studio. Студия выдает, что сборка успешно завершена, в диспетчере задач появляется процесс, но окно не запускается. Проблема появилась вчера, сегодня утром когда включил ноут из спящего режима, программа оказалась уже открытой в нескольких экземплярах. После их закрытия все по-прежнему. 
Файлы проекта я никуда не перемещала, проблема возникла после небольших изменений в коде, но возврат обратно ничем не помог. 
Может быть, это глюк студии или Windows? Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1):

Все,  решила проблему.
Ошибка в коде, из-за которой программа запускала в цикле сложный метод. Так что программа проводила вычисления несколько часов.